# Copy multiple cells from one to multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a workbook in Excel 2007 with 52 worksheet each representing a week of the year, each worksheet is laid out the same with 16 rows and 26 columns to give me 14 personnel and 24 hours with other bits of info, title and totals etc.

Now some of the 'crew' (we are fire fighters) have changed their shift patterns and what I would like to do is copy all the updated cells from one worksheet and paste to all the other worksheets as quickly and easily as possible without having to sit and alter all the other worksheets individually.

Here's hopefully

Richard J

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like unfortunate spreadsheet design. You seem to put data into a report layout. The data should be collected in one data sheet, and the 52 weekly sheets should be reports off that data. Then changes to what data appears where would be a lot easer, because you only need to change the source data. You may want to provide a bit more detail about the layout and what you want to copy to where to get any meaningful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format, headers and the data you have to paste are all in the same order as the first page, update the data you want to copy in the first page.  Then copy the data you would want to paste in other 51 sheets.  Click on sheet2 and select (click on the sheets at the bottom) the rest of 50 sheets by mouse and paste the data in the sheet which is now open other than the first sheet.  You should find the data pasted in all of the 51 sheets now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the layout of the data are parallel across all sheets:

1. Go to the first worksheet & press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy the updated cells.
2. Click the tab for the second sheet & while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button, click the tab for the last worksheet. Sheets 2 up to 52 should now be highlighted, like Sheet2 to Sheet10 below:

   [image]
3. With the rest of the sheets still selected, paste the updated cells where you want them.

The rest of the sheets should now contain the updated info.

You can also update all the sheets at the same time. Just select all the sheets using the method mentioned in Step 2 above (click the first sheet, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> & click the last sheet), and then update the information. The rest of the sheets get updated as you go.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I'm going to try it now and I will post back.